# Azure SQL as a service linked services to an on-premise SQL Server

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

It would appear that there is no way to make use of linked serveries when running SQL as a services and then try and connect to a on premises SQL server. There is only a way to make use of linked services if both db's are in the cloud. Is there a work around other than moving on prem db to Azure and making use of data-factory

Arthur

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to connect on-prem SQL with an IaaS SQL, you need to install Data Management Gateway. For both on-prem and IaaS SQL, use OnPremisesSqlServer as the linked service type, then you can specify gatewayName. Refer to the document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-sqlserver-connector

Comment: Thanks. Will this act the same way as linked services within SQL Server?

Comment: What do you mean the "linked services within SQL Server". Do you mean linked server? Linked service is just a virtual concept to represent external connection in data factory. The actual connection happens between Data Management Gateway and on-prem SQL/IaaS SQL by parsing the linked service definition at runtime.